# getting different querys work on the same page

Tags: php, sql, search

I have some problems getting my form to work, im trying to to a condition with a submit button, let me give you some code:

```
<form id=\"form1\" name=\"hae_form\" method=\"post\" action=\"\" />
                <input type=\"text\" id=\"state\"  name=\"state\" />
<input type=\"submit\" class=\"input\" name=\"Submit\" value=\"hae\"/>



if(isset($_POST['hae_form'])){
    $hakusana = $_POST['state'];
    $kysely1 = "SELECT * FROM asiakkaat WHERE Sukunimi = $hakusana";
    $result = mysql_query("$kysely1") 
              or die(mysql_error()); 
} else {
   $kysely2 ="SELECT * FROM asiakkaat";
   $result = mysql_query("$kysely2") 
   or die(mysql_error()); 
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    i get the results here by query "kysely2"
}
```

the query "kysely2" works good, but im not sure what im supposed to but on the form action so i could get the query "kysely1" results with just clicking the submit?

PHP_self didnt work for as a action, it changes the url when i use the submit button and thats why it leads to a different .php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this : `if(isset($_POST['hae_form'])){`

to `if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){`

Change this : `$kysely1 = "SELECT * FROM asiakkaat WHERE Sukunimi = $hakusana";`

to `$kysely1 = "SELECT * FROM asiakkaat WHERE Sukunimi = '".$hakusana."'";`

Comment: @EmmiLehto : Accept the answer if you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

First of all change

```
if(isset($_POST['hae_form']))
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
```

and i think your column `Sukunimi` is having varchar datatype use single quote around it

```
 $kysely1 = "SELECT * FROM asiakkaat WHERE Sukunimi = '$hakusana'";
                                                      ^         ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check form post using below code.

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && $_POST['Submit'] == "hae"){
```

above code make sure that form with `submit` button value equal `hae` is posted.

**Query**

```
$kysely1 = "SELECT * FROM asiakkaat WHERE Sukunimi = '".$hakusana."'";
```

also do not use `mysql_*` as its deprecated from now.